# Amazon Redshift MAX_STEPS limitation

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

When I try to run a huge query over Amazon Redshift I get the following error:

> "m_num_steps < MAX_STEPS - exceeded maximum plan steps of 100"

There are 4 tables at Redshift. The fact table has about 400 million rows. The query is a "WITH" clause with multiple joins, agregations, analytic and window functions.

The question is: there is a way to avoid this "MAX_STEPS = 100" limitation?

The query (simplified):

```
WITH 
                -- Regr
                    a27 as (
                     select id_uc, case when count(*) = 0 or VAR_POP(numero_de_meses) = 0 then null else trunc(((SUM(consumo_normalizado * numero_de_meses) - SUM(numero_de_meses) * SUM(consumo_normalizado) / count(*)) / count(*)) / VAR_POP(numero_de_meses), 2) end N2542, case when count(*) = 0 or STDDEV_POP(consumo_normalizado) = 0 or STDDEV_POP(numero_de_meses) = 0 then null else trunc(POWER(((SUM(consumo_normalizado * numero_de_meses) - SUM(numero_de_meses) * SUM(consumo_normalizado) / count(*)) / count(*)) / (STDDEV_POP(consumo_normalizado) * STDDEV_POP(numero_de_meses)), 2), 2) end  N2554 from (
                                select id_uc, 
                                rank() over (partition by canal.id_uc order by canal.data_referencia) numero_de_meses,
                                        case 
                                            when stddev(consumo_faturado) over (partition by canal.id_uc) <> 0 
                                            then (consumo_faturado - avg(consumo_faturado) over (partition by canal.id_uc)) / stddev(consumo_faturado) over (partition by canal.id_uc)
                                            else null end as consumo_normalizado                
                                from fato_uc canal 
                                where exists (select 1 from eventos_resultado_atual evt where canal.id_uc = evt.id_uc and canal.data_referencia between E_Fat_12_meses_atras and ultimo_faturamento)
                            ) group by id_uc)
                -- Regr
                    ,a28 as (
                     select id_uc, case when count(*) = 0 or VAR_POP(numero_de_meses) = 0 then null else case when count(*) = 0 or VAR_POP(numero_de_meses) = 0 then null else trunc(((SUM(consumo_normalizado * numero_de_meses) - SUM(numero_de_meses) * SUM(consumo_normalizado) / count(*)) / count(*)) / VAR_POP(numero_de_meses), 2) end end N2545, case when count(*) = 0 or STDDEV_POP(consumo_normalizado) = 0 or STDDEV_POP(numero_de_meses) = 0 then null else trunc(POWER(((SUM(consumo_normalizado * numero_de_meses) - SUM(numero_de_meses) * SUM(consumo_normalizado) / count(*)) / count(*)) / (STDDEV_POP(consumo_normalizado) * STDDEV_POP(numero_de_meses)), 2), 2) end  N2557 from (
                                select id_uc, 
                                rank() over (partition by canal.id_uc order by canal.data_referencia) numero_de_meses,
                                        case 
                                            when stddev(consumo_faturado) over (partition by canal.id_uc) <> 0 
                                            then (consumo_faturado - avg(consumo_faturado) over (partition by canal.id_uc)) / stddev(consumo_faturado) over (partition by canal.id_uc)
                                            else null end as consumo_normalizado                
                                from fato_uc canal 
                                where exists (select 1 from eventos_resultado_atual evt where canal.id_uc = evt.id_uc and canal.data_referencia between E_Fat_12_meses_atras and E_2457)
                            ) group by id_uc)

                -- Corr
                    ,a65 as (
                     select evt.id_uc, case when count(*) = 0 or STDDEV_POP(c1.avg_cons) = 0 or STDDEV_POP(c2.consumo_faturado) = 0 then null else trunc(((SUM(c1.avg_cons * c2.consumo_faturado) - SUM(c2.consumo_faturado) * SUM(c1.avg_cons) / count(*)) / count(*)) / (STDDEV_POP(c1.avg_cons) * STDDEV_POP(c2.consumo_faturado)), 2) end N2720
                                from eventos_resultado_atual evt inner join VIZ_FAT c1 on evt.id_uc = c1.id_uc
                                inner join fato_uc c2 on evt.id_uc = c2.id_uc and date_trunc('month', c1.mes_ref) = date_trunc('month', c2.data_referencia)
                                where c1.mes_ref between E_Fat_12_meses_atras and ultimo_faturamento
                                and c2.data_referencia between E_Fat_12_meses_atras and ultimo_faturamento
                                group by evt.id_uc)
                -- Corr
                    ,a66 as (
                     select evt.id_uc, case when count(*) = 0 or STDDEV_POP(c1.avg_cons) = 0 or STDDEV_POP(c2.consumo_faturado) = 0 then null else trunc(((SUM(c1.avg_cons * c2.consumo_faturado) - SUM(c2.consumo_faturado) * SUM(c1.avg_cons) / count(*)) / count(*)) / (STDDEV_POP(c1.avg_cons) * STDDEV_POP(c2.consumo_faturado)), 2) end N2723
                                from eventos_resultado_atual evt inner join VIZ_FAT c1 on evt.id_uc = c1.id_uc
                                inner join fato_uc c2 on evt.id_uc = c2.id_uc and date_trunc('month', c1.mes_ref) = date_trunc('month', c2.data_referencia)
                                where c1.mes_ref between E_Fat_12_meses_atras and E_2457
                                and c2.data_referencia between E_Fat_12_meses_atras and E_2457
                                group by evt.id_uc)

                SELECT *
                FROM eventos_resultado_atual 
                                    left join a27 on eventos_resultado_atual.id_uc = a27.id_uc 
                                    left join a28 on eventos_resultado_atual.id_uc = a28.id_uc 
                                    left join a65 on eventos_resultado_atual.id_uc = a65.id_uc 
                                    left join a66 on eventos_resultado_atual.id_uc = a66.id_uc
```

Comment: Can you share the query and the explain plan ?

Comment: Still occuring as of Aug 2015.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to break your query into a few sub queries and insert the results into tables along the process. Please share query and I will help you break it up into a few queries that will run more efficient. If you can also share the redshift provided explain plain I I can go over how to use that to do what I would do...

Comment: I'm looking for a way to overcome this Redshift's MAX_STEPS limitation. Since the query runs without problems on Oracle.

Comment: Can you provide the query?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with redshift and as always amazon have no solution,try breaking the query in little tasks, be careful with working with lot of data in redshift have serious issues with big data